# React: Component re-renders only when method is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react. I want to write a component that shows shows a loading animation for 5 seconds when a button is pressed, and other times display a simple "hello world". Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactLoading from 'react-loading';

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
      }
    }
}


class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [], // will hold the results from our ajax call
      loading: false, // will be true when ajax request is running
    }
  }



    test1() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
                sleep(5000);
                this.setState({loading: false});

            });
        }.bind(this), 0);
    }

    onClick = () => {
        this.test1();
    }

  render() {
    const { data, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>
          Load Data
        </button>

        {loading ? <ReactLoading className={'my-icon'} type={"spin"} color={"black"} height={'50%'} width={'100%'} delay={100}/> : 'HelloWorld'}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Test;
```

However, after pressing button and state change of `{loading: true}`, component doesn't update. It updates only after that 5 seconds of sleep, so i never see loading icon.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded; you're blocking the browser for five seconds from doing *anything* at all. You need `this.setState({loading: true}, () => setTimeout(() => this.setState({loading: false}), 5000))`

Comment: @ChrisG Worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, no need of external sleep function,

```
test1() {
   this.setState({ loading: true }, () => setTimout(()=>{this.setState({loading: false})},5000))
}
```